# syslog udp load balancing and failover with keepalived

Tags: load-balancing, failover, udp, keepalived, graylog

I have a simple two host graylog cluster for which i need to load balance udp syslog traffic, I'm using keepalived, floating ip and load balancing work perfectly, but it still directs traffic to all nodes even to those on which healthcheck failed, i want it to direct a traffic to healthy nodes only, here's my keepalived.conf:

```
global_defs {
  enable_script_security
  script_user root root
  router_id LVS_MASTER
}
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  state MASTER
  interface enp0s3
  virtual_router_id 216
  priority 200
  advert_int 1
  preempt_delay 30
  authentication {
    auth_type PASS
    auth_pass redacted
  }
  virtual_ipaddress {
    192.168.0.X
  }
}    
virtual_server 192.168.0.X 514 {
  delay_loop 1
  protocol UDP
  lb_algo wrr # makes no difference
  lb_kind NAT # no difference too
  real_server 192.168.0.A 514 {
    weight 1
    HTTP_GET {
      url {
        path "/api/system/lbstatus"
        status_code 200
      }
      connect_timeout 3
      connect_port 9000
    }
  }    
  real_server 192.168.0.B 514 {
    weight 1
    HTTP_GET {
      url {
        path "/api/system/lbstatus"
        status_code 200
      }
      connect_timeout 3
      connect_port 9000
    }
  }
}
```

it's the same on the second host, except `state BACKUP` and lower priority, both keepalived instances cooperate, I see healthchecks fails and successes, adding and removing services from and to VS etc in logs, but both hosts receive data even though healthcheck on one failed (verified with tcpdump)

What am I doing wrong?